# Should I pass array or pointer?

Tags: design, c++, libraries

I am writing a C++ library (but prefer C style interface functions) and one of the function returns array of floats. I am not sure if I should pass pointer or fixed array to get this data?

```
// in the library header file
#define MAX_ITEMS_SIZE   1000

int getData(float * data, int &size );
```

or

```
int getData(float (&data)[MAX_ITEMS_SIZE], int & size )
```

If I am passing the pointer, the client should allocate MAX_ITEMS_SIZE for it. Is that a reasonable and fair expectations? Passing it as array forces the client to pass the max memory required. Which one is better?

Some more background, the MAX_ITEMS_SIZE is the maximum number of floats that can be returned. In reality the array will contain less items which is filled in the size parameter. The function returns int which is error code where zero means no error.

My overall goal is how to return the data which is array of floats in easy to understand and reliable way. Even though I am using C++, I would like to stick with C interface functions so the library can be used more widely.

Comment: If you want to remain C compatible you should update your question to reflect that fact.

Comment: @Ramhound done, just updated the question.

Comment: References are C++. If you need extern "C" compatibility, make sure it's all clean C.

Answer (score 9):

> I am writing a C++ library

So why don't you use C++ instead of C?

```
   getData(std::vector<float> &data);
```

is most probably what you want. And even when programming in C, do yourself a favor and avoid to use fixed limits like `MAX_ITEMS_SIZE`, that number will almost be too big (wasting resources) or too small (which means your program might not work as intended).

Comment: or `std::vector<float> getData()` and throw an exception on error.

Comment: I thought passing STL containers is not safe across different compilers when it comes to exposing them from a library?

Comment: @zadane: are you really going to distribute your lib across different compilers in binary form?

Comment: I will only provide .lib and header file and I would expect it would work with at least windows compilers who knows from VC6 to VS2013 and gcc. I don't want to worry about that. Also even though I am using C++, I would like interface to be in C functions so they can be used more widely.

Comment: @zadane: you did not mention anything of that in your question. But if that's the case, I suggest you use ratchedfreak's answer.

Comment: `So why don't you use C++ instead of C?` I don't get why people get hooked up about this. He is technically using C++.

Comment: @ThomasEding: that was actually not my point.

Answer (score 5):

Typically you would see

```
size_t getDate(float* buffer, size_t bufferSize);
```

The return value is the amount of data returned and you pass in how large your buffer actually is.

EDIT: In your comments to want to have an error return code and remain C compatible, if so I suggest doing like Doc brown suggested:

```
int getDate(float* buffer, size_t bufferSize, size_t &dataSizeReturned);
```

Comment: my return type is int where zero means success and non-zero indicates error. Sorry I missed that in my post, will update.

Comment: @zadane you can still return 0 to say nothing was returned, though no complex error types

Comment: return a negative number for error

Comment: @kevincline you'd need to return an int then

Comment: 0 return means no error occurred but any other int indicates a particular error.

Comment: @zadane make all error code negative and return the size, test for error is `int read = getData(buff, buffsize);if(read<0){/*ERROR*/}`

Comment: @zadane: its pretty obvious how to change this answer to what you want: `int getDate(float* buffer, size_t bufferSize, size_t &dataSizeReturned);` where the return code is your error code.

Comment: What I am not sure about is the client is passing the buffer pointer and size, it doesn't seem to recognize how much buffer size the function actually needs which is defined by #define in header file.  I guess first thing my function has to to do is check if the buffer size is at least as big as `MAX_ITEMS_SIZE`

Comment: @zadane looks like a new error; besides the error code return you can also throw an exception to signal failure

Comment: @ratchetfreak: throwing an exception is not a good idea when the API shall be kept C compatible, as the OP wrote in another comment.

Comment: @zadane: please, **don't** use fixed values like `MAX_ITEMS_SIZE`, take this recommendation seriously, this will help you to avoid much trouble,

Comment: @DocBrown but how does a client know how much buffer size should they allocate?

Comment: @zadane documentation or a helper function, another option is to allow partial returns so the next call will return the data portion that couldn't be returned in the last call

Comment: since we are at it, I always thought a dry run of the same function can be used to return the required size but I have never seen this anywhere and don't know if I want to be the first :) For example `getData(NULL, bfrSize)` where the pointer is NULL, the function knows just to return the required size in bfrSize. Would that be too bad?

Comment: @zadane: I would probably prefer to use a separate function for querying the size (if you want to avoid the library to do the `malloc` for the client.) You can also return a specific error code is the provided buffer size is too small, pass the required size in "dataSizeReturned" and let the client make a second try with an increased buffer size.

Comment: **Please do not use comments for chatting unless it is about clarification or elaboration on a question or answer.  If you would like to continue this conversation then I recommend visiting the chat room.  Thank you.**

Answer (score 2):

My few cents... Since you want to maintain compatibility with C, I would say - neither. C does not have a "reference" concept and it also does not allow for passing array by reference. Furthermore, C++ has [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) so unless the function is declared with C-linkage, it would not be possible to call it from a C code in a straightforward way.

Therefore, I'd say that for the purpose of compatibility with C, the signature should look like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int getData(float *data, int* size)

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```